# Can you target yourself with touch spells

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, spell-components, touch-attacks

I have been asked by one of my players “can I touch myself with a spell the has a range of touch?” Most touch spell say “you touch a willing creature of your choice,” or something along those lines. And my judgement is that you’re willing if you want to impose the effects on yourself. So I say, a touch spell is a spell that is kind of like a self that you can also use on other creatures or characters. Please correct me if I’m wrong and tell if I’m right.

Answer (score 2):

#### You can target yourself with Touch-range spells

The rules on Spellcasting, in particular, the rules on "[Targeting Yourself](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#TargetingYourself)" state:

> [...] If a spell targets a creature of your choice, you can choose yourself, unless the creature must be hostile or specifically a creature other than you. If you are in the area of effect of a spell you cast, you can target yourself. [...]

As such, if a spell has a range of "Touch" and does not specifically require you to target a creature that is not yourself, you can target yourself with that spell, assuming you are able to actually target yourself in the first place.

I can't actually think of any Touch-range spells that require you to target a creature other than yourself, but there are still Touch-range spells that you simply cannot target yourself with due to other targeting requirements. For example, the *beast sense* spell only targets beasts, so you (most likely) cannot target yourself with that spell.

The rules on "[Range](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Range)" also state the following (emphasis mine) which agrees with this stance that you can target yourself with Touch-range spells:

> [...] Some spells can target only a creature **(including you)** that you touch. [...]